# Matlab: DNA Sequence Comparison

Tags: matlab, dna-sequence

I want to compare two DNA sequences to each other. However, I would like to take the first protein for the first sequence and compare it to the full length of the second sequence, and so on.

E.g.

DNASequence1: ABCDEFGHIJKA

DNASequence2: ABCHIKABTIYO

So it takes the first protein in the sequence A and compares it to the second sequence, producing two matches. It then takes B and compares it, producing another two matches. And so on until all the proteins have been compared.

Comment: Hint: See what `DNASequence2 == DNASequence1(1)` gives you.

Comment: Does this do the job? `sum(~bsxfun(@minus,dna1,dna2'),1)`

Comment: afraid not hbaderts.
thanks @beaker, i understand the result this is producing now. will try and come up with some code now!

Comment: Another hint: You will probably want to use `bsxfun` with `@eq`.

Comment: Any further clues @beaker ? if possible, I would like this set up in some form of loop, as the DNA lengths could be say 15 for two sequences and 20 for another.

Comment: Loops are lame. `bsxfun` is more fun. It even has "fun" in the name. I'll type up an answer since I can't give any more hints without actually giving it all away ;)

Comment: @user5655305 If the answer is not quite what you need, let me know. Of course it's possible to do it with loops as well, it's just that vectorized approaches are generally more efficient than loops in MATLAB.

Comment: @beaker thanks for your help. im going to have another look at this and see if I can manipulate the outputs how I need to. thanks so far.

Comment: @beaver this is great function. but, what about if i wanted to compare DNA of different lengths? i am completely unable to modify the DNA sequences.

Comment: @user5655305 If you have sequences of different lengths, then the resulting matrix will simply not be square.

Comment: @beaker nope, error messages says they must be of equal size. help for the function says the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this with a loop, but `bsxfun` is more concise (and probably faster) and gives the same results:

```
A = 'ABCDEFGHIJKA';   %// I shortened the variable names...
B = 'ABCHIKABTIYO';   %// because I don't like typing.

C = bsxfun(@eq, B, A')

C =

   1   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0
   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0
   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   1   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
   1   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0
```

Each row of `C` is `1` where the corresponding element from `A` occurs in `B`. For instance, row `9` gives all of the occurrences of the letter `I` in sequence `B`.

This also works in cases where the sequences are of different lengths:

```
>> D = [B B]
D = ABCHIKABTIYOABCHIKABTIYO

>> bsxfun(@eq, D, A')
ans =

   1   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0
   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0
   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   1   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
   1   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0
```

Comment: thanks for this. sorry I was having a seriously dumb moment before!